# JavaScript - How to get style in range that across two tag?

Tags: javascript, styles, range, selection

i can use

```
var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
```

to get range, and use

```
var color = window.getComputedStyle(range, null)['color']
```

to get font style 
but when i select ranges that across the two tags, 
range will be range's parent node
example:

```
<div>
   ab
   <font color="#0000FF">cdef</font>
   <font color="#0000FF">ghij</font>
   kl
<div>
```

when i select "de" commonAncestorContainer will return

```
<font color="#0000FF">cdef</font>
```

when i select "efgh" commonAncestorContainer will return all div

how can i get "ef" and "gh" style? thanks!!